# How to send HTML FORM data from one page to another using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to send HTML FORM data from one page to another using Javascript. Here is my code. Suppose I am entering any text in the "NAME" field of FORM.html page. The text will display on the DISPLAY.html page after submitting. How to do it? Please help

**FORM.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>FORM</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="GET" action="display.html">
NAME: <input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**DISPLAY.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Display</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="show">
Name: <!-- want to display the name here -->
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you don't use a server technology like PHP you could use Javascript to set Cookies or use the browser's session storage . But this is generally not the way forms and applications work.

Check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Answer (score 0):

You save the name in the url when you submit the FORM.html form

You can read the name from the url when you load the DISPLAY.html form with a javascript function that runs in the onload page.

You have to replace your DISPLAY.html for this one:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Display</title>
</head>
<body onload="getName()">
<p id="show">
<div id='myDiv'>Name: <!-- want to display the name here -->
</div>
</p>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getName()
    {   
        var name = window.location.href.split("?name=")[1].s‌​plit("+").join(" ");
        var fieldNameElement = document.getElementById('myDiv');
        var oldText=fieldNameElement.innerHTML;
        fieldNameElement.innerHTML = oldText+' '+name;
    }
</script>
</html>
```

It worked for me at least with Chrome

In case you have more elements in the url, you can use split and get the elements between "&"

Regards

Comment: Why use 3 variables to get the name when you could do it with one?
var name = window.location.href.split("?name=")[1];

Comment: Yes, your solution is more eficient. I edit mine with yours, Thanks!

Comment: thanks... this code is working.. but a problem is that it do not printing the spaces. Suppose I enter "Danny Boyle". It is displaying "Danny+Boyle".

Comment: I edited my respone replacing this line: var name = window.location.href.split("?name=")[1] for this one: var name = window.location.href.split("?name=")[1].split("+").join(" ");  This change will replace all "+" for " "

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to done it by the `JavaScript` then you can use `window.localStorage` property to store the `name` object locally.

**Form.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>FORM</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form" method="GET" action="display.html">
NAME: <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm()">
</form>
<script>
function submitForm(){
    if(typeof(localStorage) != "undefined"){
        localStorage.name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    }
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Display.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Display</title>
</head>
<body onload="setData()">
<p id="show">
Name: <!-- want to display the name here -->
</p>
<script>
function setData(){
    if(typeof(localStorage) != "undefined"){
        document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = localStorage.name;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. It is working for me, but a problem is that when I am pressing "Enter" button to submit the name, it is displaying the previous name. New name is not showing.